# How can I change the default time zone in MongoDB using mongosh?

Tags: mongodb, timezone, mongo-shell

I'm working with MongoDB and using the mongosh shell. I'm trying to set a specific time zone for my MongoDB instance, but it seems like the usual approach using setParameter and the "timeZone" parameter isn't working as expected.

Here's what I tried:

```js
db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, timeZone: "Asia/Colombo"})
```

Unfortunately, I got an error saying that "timeZone" is not recognized.

I'd really appreciate some guidance on how to change the default time zone in MongoDB when using the mongosh shell. Is there another way to achieve this, or am I missing something in my approach?

Comment: AFAIK, MongoDB doesn't have the concept of a "default time zone".  It works exclusively in UTC.  You either handle time zone conversions in your application logic, or you use the `timezone` parameter in aggregations such as `$dateToString` (and others).  Is there something that makes you believe that a "default time zone" should exist and it's in a parameter called `timeZone`?  I searched the docs and found nothing.